# Signal jammer circuit design

Tags: communication, frequency

[image]

[This is a circut for a jammer](http://www.electronicshub.org/mobile-jammer-circuit/) for the 450Mhz , but my calculation says it's for 277Mhz.

If I want to prepare for a gsm 900 , what changes would I have to make .

Comment: A jammer for GSM? Illegal in almost all jurisdictions...

Comment: Reading the web page where it came from it's clear the author has no clue how it works.  The BF494 is an npn, and looks to be obsolete.

Answer (score 4):

No doubt your answer can be found here: [Telecom Regulatory Authority of India](http://www.trai.gov.in/Content/index.aspx).